# ISO permitted RF emission spectrum for medical devices in hospitals

Tags: rf, electromagnetic, spectrum, iso

I've been searching to find the electromagnetic compatibility requirements for medical devices to be used in hospital but cannot find the correct ISO standard.  The list [here](https://www.greenlight.guru/blog/iso-standards) only lists implantable devices.

I spent considerable time on this back in 2021 so I know the document exists as I used it previously to guide my development.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to the ISO document that details the allowed RF spectrum for medical devices?

Comment: Doesn't it come under [IEC 60601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60601)?